# how to inject locals to a controller dynamically?

Tags: angularjs

We mostly write our controllers in this fashion:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
//do something with $scope & $location
});
```

I am writing a directive, and I am faced with a scenario where I have to render a view based on a certain controller instance. The directive will be called as follows:

```
<my-directive src="srcVar" controller="myctrl"></my-directive>
```

This directive takes care of loading the template specified by `srcVar` and instancing the controller using the $controller service. So there are few lines in my code that does like:

```
$controller(çtrlExp, {'$scope' : scope.$new() });
```

The above works for simple cases where the controller has only one argument. For the above controller example, you can stuff work the following manner:

```
var locals = { '$scope' : $scope.$new(), '$location' : $injector.get('$location') };
$controller('MyCtrl', locals);
```

Now how to write it for a generic case, where the user's controller can include any number of injectable constructs like services, values, constants, etc, all of which are usually defined during module creation.

Ps: if you are looking for workable code...refer my github repo: https://github.com/deostroll/ngFrame/blob/master/app/scripts/viewutils.js . This is still a work in progress sort of library.

Comment: I think you only need to add the `$scope` in your locals the rest will be done automatically by Angular's DI. Please have a look at this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zr197o7r/).

Comment: @AWolf this is the answer. Thanks. For proper closure, please write your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to add the `$scope` in your locals the rest will be done automatically by Angular's DI.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zr197o7r/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('mainController', MainController)
.directive('myDirective', MyDirective);

function MainController($scope, $location) {
    this.testTemplate = 'testTemplate.html';
    console.log($location, $scope); // everything available here!
}

MainController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location'];

function MyDirective($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'hello',
        controller: function($scope, $attrs, $controller){
            console.log($attrs.controller, $scope);
            $controller($attrs.controller, {'$scope': new $scope.$new()});
        },
        compile: function(element, attrs, $scope) {
            var template = angular.element(document.getElementById(attrs.src))
                .html();
            
            console.log(template);
            element.replaceWith(template);
            
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                //template is compiled now and in DOM, add scope variable
                scope.hello='Hello from directive';
            };
        }
    };
}

MyDirective.$inject = ['$compile'];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="testTemplate.html">
        <div>
            <h1>Test template</h1>
            {{hello}}
        </div>
    </script>
    <my-directive src="testTemplate.html" controller="mainController"></my-directive>
</div>
```